# Different element order on HTML when printing on Edge and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing, microsoft-edge

I'm styling a print page with CSS. The page is printing exactly how I want it on Chrome and FireFox. However, Edge and IE are displaying the elements on the wrong order.

HTML (notice the order):

```
<tbody id="part-01">content 1</tbody>
<tbody id="part-02">content 2</tbody>
<div id="insQt-disclaimers">content 3</div>
```

CSS:

```
#part-01 {width:100%;}
#part-02{width:40%; float:right;}
#insQt-disclaimers {width: 50%; float:left; display:block;}
```

Here's a screenshot of the printing preview on Chrome and FireFox (displaying correctly): https://gyazo.com/f5298fe370a9123f5c24325a63de7791

Here's a screenshot of the printing preview on Edge and Internet Explorer (displaying incorrectly) https://gyazo.com/fcedf957bb69d02574a7198bc56a055a

As you can see, the content 2 is misplaced. Why is the content 2 moving to the top above the content 1?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using the only above code you provided. The outcome of the above code is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VUSQ.png. Could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can test it in our sides and see how to help? Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 4):

It would help to know what styling was applied. I would guess it is something with the display attribute as I know it doesn't always play nice in printing.

You can call me lazy if you want (I am often lazy), BUT my solution would be to set those both as being full width with a custom printing css as it wouldn't change the semantics of the layout.

https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/

Comment: It wasn't the answer I was looking for, but I ended up doing that. lol. I guess I that lazy too.

Comment: Lazy might be a 4 letter word but it isn't necessarily a bad thing.